# Azure Policy - CosmoDB Resctriction on RU (Throughout)

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I want to deny if someone is creating more than 600 ru/s throughout. Here's my policy rule :

```
{
    "if": {
        "allOf": [
            {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/throughputSettings"
            },
            {
                "field":"Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/throughputSettings/default.resource.throughput",
                "greater" : "600"     
            }

        ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "Deny"
    }
}
```

But the deny doesn't work when I put more than 600 ru/s.

Comment: It's likely that policy might be still in Compliance state of "Not started". Did you check the Compliance state?

Comment: yes it is 100% compliant and it's not working

Comment: What's the [mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#mode) on your policy? If it's "Indexed", you need to change it to "All"

Comment: @sapphiremirage yes it's actually on "All"

Answer (score 1):

I inquired more about the policy to deny/restrict from creating of containers if throughput exceeds a maximum.
I raised a GitHub issue and got the answer that-

Throughput is not set on initial create via the throughputSettings API. See this template for an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-sql-with-resource-manager#create-resource
There is not currently a policy alias for options.throughput on the container since it is not returned on future GET requests.

Please refer this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/issues/552) for information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your great help! I'll look at it more closely